# FileReadFailure in Automation Studio Import Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, import

We have a simple workflow in Automation Studio that triggers when a file with a certain name pattern + %%Year%%*%%Month%%*%%Day%% is dropped in the "import" FTP folder.

We are having problems with one specific automation that is just a File Drop + Import File. I'm receiving this e-mail report with the error: **(Exception: FileReadFailure. ValidationResultCode:FileReadFailure (IMPORT_INFO))**.

The file that is dropped in the import folder is a .csv like all the others that we have (this is one of nine automation that we created, and they are all the same and the .csv files are all created in the same way).

I'm not getting proper help from Salesforce support, so I thought someone here could help me. This error "Exception: FileReadFailure" doesn't tell me anything that I could look for, so I'm out of ways to solve this problem.

The automation starts (File Drop) and initializes the "Import File" activity, and there I got the error with 0 rows inserted in the Data Extension.

Comment: Have you validated that the Import Activity is correctly set to ingest the CSV file? It sounds like you did exploration on the files themselves and how they are set up, but if someone accidently put the wrong info in the Import Activity that instead could be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party for the original asker, but I ran into this same error this week and wanted to share what I found for anyone finding this post in the future (like I did). SFMC support wasn't able to diagnose anything other than telling me I must have canceled the import (I didn't). But after digging through our file, I found that one of the text fields had an extra double quote `"` in the middle of it, which I believe was being misinterpreted as an unclosed text qualifier, breaking all of the columns after it. Fixing that and reimporting was successful.

So for future people running into this error - I don't know if it is always related to an unclosed text qualifier or column delimiter, but that's a good place to start. Opening the file in Excel and filtering on columns should make it easy to find if you have any broken rows with offset columns.